# Passing multiple quoted arguments to command in bourne shell

Tags: command-line, sh, portability, argument-passing, quoting

I have a utility (`myutil`) that I need to pass multiple parameters.  The parameters may(will) contain backslashes and spaces and therefore need to be enclosed in single quotes.  An example run of this utility is:

```
myutil setOptions "ONE\APPLE" "ONE\PEAR" "TWO\RED GRAPE" "TWO\TOMATO"
```

I am working on a script which will read these parameters from a multi-line file and feed them into the script.  The input file myinput.txt looks like this:

```
# cat myinput.txt
ONE\APPLE
ONE\PEAR
TWO\RED GRAPE
TWO\TOMATO
```

I am using the following code to parse the file and execute `myutil`.  The script reads each line as an argument, and encloses it in double quotes (as `myutil` will expect for values with spaces or special characters) and creates a single variable to hold the entire argument string:

```
#!/bin/sh
MYCOMMAND=myutil
if [ -f myinput.txt ]; then
    ARGSLIST=`cat myinput.txt| sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | awk '{ printf "%s ",  $0  }'`
    $MYCOMMAND setOptions "${ARGSLIST}"
    printf "%s\n" "$MYCOMMAND setOptions ${ARGSLIST}"
fi
```

As I might expect, the screen output of this command looks as expected:

```
myutil setOptions "ONE\APPLE" "ONE\PEAR" "TWO\RED GRAPE" "TWO\TOMATO"
```

However, this is not actually what is being executed based on how `myutil` would normally process this command.  Instead, `myutil` is processing this as if ALL the arguments were also enclosed within single quotes.  Running this debug under `sh` doesn't reflect this:

```
+ MYCOMMAND=myutil
+ [ -f myinput.txt ]
+ awk { printf "%s ",  $0  }
+ sed -e s/^/"/g -e s/$/"/g
+ cat myinput.txt
+ ARGSLIST="ONE\APPLE" "ONE\PEAR" "TWO\RED GRAPE" "TWO\TOMATO"
+ myutil setOptions "ONE\APPLE" "ONE\PEAR" "TWO\RED GRAPE" "TWO\TOMATO"
+ printf %s\n myutil setOptions "ONE\APPLE" "ONE\PEAR" "TWO\RED GRAPE" "TWO\TOMATO"
myutil setOptions "ONE\APPLE" "ONE\PEAR" "TWO\RED GRAPE" "TWO\TOMATO"
```

HOWEVER, running debug under `bash` seems to show what is really being executed:

```
+ MYCOMMAND=myutil
+ '[' -f myinput.txt ']'
++ awk '{ printf "%s ",  $0  }'
++ sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g'
++ cat myinput.txt
+ ARGSLIST='"ONE\APPLE" "ONE\PEAR" "TWO\RED GRAPE" "TWO\TOMATO" '
+ myutil setOptions '"ONE\APPLE" "ONE\PEAR" "TWO\RED GRAPE" "TWO\TOMATO" '
+ printf '%s\n' 'myutil setOptions "ONE\APPLE" "ONE\PEAR" "TWO\RED GRAPE" "TWO\TOMATO" '
myutil setOptions "ONE\APPLE" "ONE\PEAR" "TWO\RED GRAPE" "TWO\TOMATO"
```

You can see the debug line which shows as:

```
+ myutil setOptions '"ONE\APPLE" "ONE\PEAR" "TWO\RED GRAPE" "TWO\TOMATO" '
```

That line is actually what is being executed based on the output I see in my util, but what gets printed to the screen is the aforementioned minus the single quotes:

```
myutil setOptions "ONE\APPLE" "ONE\PEAR" "TWO\RED GRAPE" "TWO\TOMATO"
```

I need what is being displayed to the screen to be what is actually executed, not the version with the single quotes as that provides one giant parameter to `myutil` which is worthless.

**I have two solutions, neither of which I'm sure is the best way to handle this.**

*The first is to simply use eval:*

```
#!/bin/sh
MYCOMMAND=myutil
if [ -f myinput.txt ]; then
    ARGSLIST=`cat myinput.txt| sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | awk '{ printf "%s ",  $0  }'`
    eval $MYCOMMAND setOptions "${ARGSLIST}"
    printf "%s\n" "$MYCOMMAND setOptions ${ARGSLIST}"
fi
```

*The second is to use xargs:*

```
#!/bin/sh
MYCOMMAND=myutil
if [ -f myinput.txt ]; then
    ARGSLIST=`cat myinput.txt| sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | awk '{ printf "%s ",  $0  }'`
    printf "%s\n" "$ARGSLIST" | xargs $MYCOMMAND setOptions 
    printf "%s\n" "$MYCOMMAND setOptions ${ARGSLIST}"
fi
```

I'm having a hard time believing that `xargs` is required, and I have been repeatedly reading how using `eval` is probably also not a recommended choice.

I have seen some similar topics regarding this with advice to use arrays, but I could not apply their advice properly to my example.  Additionally I need this solution to run under bourne `sh` and be as portable as possible as it will be running on most standard flavors of Linux/UNIX.  I don't believe `sh` supports arrays in the type that other solutions have recommended.

What is the best method for me to execute my command as it actually displays to the screen without the extra quoting being supplied by the shell?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a recursive shell function which reads one line from its standard input at a time to build up the command line. When no more input is available, the actual command is run with the accumulated arguments. The recursion adds some overhead, but I'm assuming the input file isn't very big.

```
run_from_file () {
   if IFS= read -r newarg; then
       run_from_file "$@" "$newarg"
   else
       "$MYCOMMAND" "$@"
   fi
}

run_from_file < myinput.txt
```

Comment: This works on most systems.  Unfortunately, `while read` under `sh`on Solaris does not support the `-r` parameter.  Without that I am unable to parse the file containing the `"\"` separators.  While I could implement this in a solution where I store the data with another separator (say `||`) and then translate it once I've read the line, I think there should perhaps be a more graceful way?  I know the limitations here are strict...why the `sh` isn't POSIX compliant I have no idea...  But thanks for the array example, it makes some other examples I have seen much clearer.

Comment: I think you may be better off ensuring that Solaris executes the script with `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` (a POSIX shell) rather than `/bin/sh` (which is the *actual* Bourne shell, from what I gather).

Comment: that would work, but then again I could just have them use `/bin/bash` on those systems.  I have been given the requirements that "bash may not be available on all systems" and therefore, the script is written to run as `#!/bin/sh`.  I'm not sure how we could ensure that the script runs with the appropriate shell.  If we placed `#!/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` at top, then any system that didn't have that path (non Solaris) will fail with `bad interpreter`.  I think the only way to choose the right one would be to have a wrapper script, which we would want to avoid.

Comment: This is getting a bit off-topic, but what runs your script? Rather than assuming the script is executable and uses a shebang, just have the runner execute the script using the correct executable.

Comment: Yes, this is an option - but not ideal for our scenario.  The script is to be delivered to the consumers and run on any systems they maintain.  The consumers may or may not be knowledgeable of the intricacies of the script code, nor should they be required to answer the question themselves of choosing the shell.  So, while development time and possibly the most graceful solution might be compromised, if the end result makes the consumer not have to make any intelligent decision and it works - then the goal is satisfied!